# profile.getinstalled() returns null every time in debug mode

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-simple-facebook

I am using this library for integrating facebook with my app  https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook.Its running in debug mode,i have a requirement to use the invite friends functionality and get the friends of users who have installed my app but both or not working.Profile.getinstalled returns null and invite friends is not showing the web view to select friends.Is this because my app is in debug mode(because its working fine with http get requests)?

Getting profile information,friends information etc are working fine.I am even able to get the user's friends who have installed my app using http get method(https://graph.facebook.com/fbid?access_token=appid|appsecret&fields=installed) but using this to check for every friend slows down the whole process.Please help me with this issue.

```
{  
   mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this);
   mSimpleFacebook.getFriends(onFriendsListener);

OnFriendsListener onFriendsListener = new OnFriendsListener() { 
         @Override
            public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {
                Boolean appInstallationStatus;
                for (int i = 0; i < friends.size(); i++) {
                  Profile E= friends.get(i);
                  if(E.getInstalled()!=null)
                  {
               System.out.println("----->"+E.getInstalled());
                       //Set a list adapter here
                  }
                }
            }


}
```

Here E.getinstalled() is always null but when i use the get method it gives me true or false.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far and what specific problems did you encounter?

Comment: I have added the code in my new edit and my problem is E.getInstalled() always returns null but http get method returns true or false..

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround.

```
@Override
    public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

        facebookFriendArrayList = new ArrayList<FacebookFriendListDTO>();

        for (Profile profile : friends) {
            friendListDto = new FacebookFriendListDTO();
            try {
                if (profile.getInstalled()) {
                    friendListDto.setUserName(profile.getName());
                    friendListDto.setUserBirthday(profile.getBirthday());
                    friendListDto.setUserId(profile.getId());
                    friendListDto.setUserProfilePic(profile.getPicture());

                    facebookFriendArrayList.add(friendListDto);
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        facebookFriendListAdapter = new friendListAdapter(getActivity(),
                facebookFriendArrayList);
        facebookFriendListView.setAdapter(facebookFriendListAdapter);
    }
```

hope that helped.

Regards,